# How to play audio file in Safari without letting anyone to directly download it?

Tags: laravel, audio, safari

I want to play audio files in the browser and don't want to let anyone 
 can directly download them from URL.
Currently, It works fine in google browser, but Safari can't even play the audio files through mine way.

I set the audio tag resource to the controller that get the audio file content through Storage::get($filename).

```html
<audio controls="controls">
    <source src="http://localhost:8000/audio/getAudio/{{ $filename }}">
</audio>
```

```
public function getAudio($filename)
{
    return Storage::get($filename);
}
```

None error message shown in the Safari console, so it's hard for me to debug.

Maybe there is another way to achieve what I want to, like using .htaccess
to prevent users to download any other audio files that not shown in the current webpage so I don't need to hide the audio files in the storage folders.

I never use .htaccess before, it may take me a while to learn it.

Comment: I think this is possible. For a browser to play an audio it has to download it first. Preventing user to have normal way to download it doesn't solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid file being downloaded, you need to add the proper headers to your response.
Something like this :

```php
public function getAudio($filename)
{
    $file = Storage::get($filename);
    return (new Response($file, 200))
           ->header('Content-Type', 'audio/aac');
}
```

You can specify the MIME type of your file in your response.
More here : [MIME Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types)